# Displaying html with a text area in a text area?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am making a private webpage to edit html and want to create a form that displays some html to allow me to edit it. An example bit of code is given below:

```
<?php 
$content='<textarea rows="50" cols="100" name="NewContent" form="contenteditform"> this is a test area</textarea> more text ';
echo' <form action="" method="post" id="contenteditform">
<textarea rows="50" cols="100" name="NewContent" form="contenteditform">'.$content.'</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="_submit" />
</form> '?>
```

However on my webpage the text area stops at `</textarea>` in the variable `$content` how can I make sure it ends it at the last one so that the hole of the verible  `$content` is displayed within my textarea?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for contenteditable. Otherwise try `$content='&lt;textarea rows="50" cols="100" name="NewContent" form="contenteditform"> this is a test area&lt;/textarea> more text ';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution (basically replacing the words textarea with textarea1 then turning it back into textarea after editing):

```
<?php 
$content='<textarea rows="50" cols="100" name="NewContent" form="contenteditform"> this is a test area</textarea> more text ';
echo' <form action="" method="post" id="contenteditform">
$content=str_replace('textarea','textarea1',$content);
<textarea rows="50" cols="100" name="NewContent" form="contenteditform">'.$content.'</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="_submit" />
</form>
 $NewContent=str_replace('textarea1','textarea',$_POST['NewContent']); '?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 rows containing the textarea you should just need

```
<?php
$content='<textarea rows="50" cols="100" name="NewContent" form="contenteditform"> this is a test area</textarea>';
echo '<form action="" method="post" id="contenteditform">'.$content.'<input type="submit" name="button" value="_submit" /></form>'
?>
```

Comment: Re-read the question. He wants the textarea to contain a textarea tag

Comment: @mplungjan I thought it was a typo

Comment: @Ian mplungjan is right, I want do want a text area in a text area.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this, i don't know if this is what you looking for

```
$content='&lt; textarea rows="50" cols="100" name="NewContent" form="contenteditform" &gt; this is a test area &lt; &#47; textarea &gt; more text ';
```

Comment: @Quantum spaghettification is this answer for your question

Comment: That is identical to the suggestion in my comment!